# Fastest way to increment counters in dictionary

Tags: python, performance, loops, dictionary, counter

What would be the fastest way to increment counters stored in a dictionary?

Because I have to do this same operation hundreds of thousand of times, I'm looking for something more efficient than what I have below:

```
def funcA(a):
    keys = [x for x in range(1, 51)]
    adict = {key: 0 for key in keys}

    for k in adict.keys():  # this is the code I would like to improve
        if k <= a:
            adict[k] += 1
        else:
            break


import timeit
number = 100000

t1 = timeit.timeit(
        'funcA(5)',
        setup="from __main__ import funcA", number=number)
print(t1)

>>> 0.42629639082588255
```

Trying to use a list comprehension instead seems to slow down everything a bit, maybe because it's lacking the `break` statement?

```
def funcB(a):
    # not working, invalid syntax
    keys = [x for x in range(1, 51)]
    adict = {key: 0 for key in keys}

    def _inc(x):
        x += 1
        return x

    [_inc(adict[k]) for k in adict.keys() if k <= a]

# Timing: 0.5831785711925477
```

Note: initially I had `if float(k) <= float(a):` but since I'm only expecting numbers (integers or floats), removing the `float()` conversion improved the code. Is this assumption reasonable?

Note2: as noted in several comments, the `break` statement can give unexpected results in the resulting dictionary, so is better to just do:

```
def funcA(a):
    keys = [x for x in range(1, 51)]
    adict = {key: 0 for key in keys}

    for k in adict:
        if k <= a:
            adict[k] += 1

# Timing: 0.5132114209700376
```

Comment: You can shorten `for k in adict.keys()` to `for k in adict`

Comment: Why not just do: `adict = {key: 1 if key <= a else 0 for key in keys}`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I want to increment the key `adict[k] += 1`

Comment: @PedroA That's exactly what Ashwini Chaudhary's suggestion does.

Comment: Also note that `dict.keys()` return a set of keys, meaning they might not come out ordered sometimes. So if `a = 20` and first key that comes out is `22`, then you would break out of loop and nothing would change.

Comment: why using a dict when the keys are integer? and why not doing `for k in range(1,a):` instead of testing k<=a ?

Comment: note: your bench is taking the list & dict building into account, which isn't what you want, because it dwarves the loop.

Comment: and yes, a `break` in a loop is a dead giveaway that your program has a performance issue. You can predict the stop condition in that case.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ oh no, it doesnt. It sets it to 1, not incrementing it. When the method is first called, it certainly is the same, on next calls it is not...

Comment: Instead of using a dict with int keys, the OP can just use an array. In case of numpy, the increment operation can be nicely vectorized as `arr[:k] += 1`.

Comment: Your functions should take the dictionary as an input parameter, not build it every time they are called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you could just use the fact that booleans (the result of the comparison) can be simply converted to integers. It may not be the fastest but it's definitely short and "relatively" fast:

```
def funcA(a):
     adict = {key: int(key <= a) for key in range(1, 51)}
```

This is assuming that the second function is actually what you want because the first one could give different results because of the `break`. Dictionaries are unordered so it could not increment some values for keys smaller or equal to `a`. Also it doesn't increment the values, it just sets them to `1` or `0` because you actually don't need addition in this case.

However, that's not necessarily the fastest way because it has to do a lot of functions calls and `int` lookups. So I'll present some more equivalent operations in order of performance (fastest to slowest):

```
def cached_version():
    range_cache = range(1, 51)
    cache = dict.fromkeys(range_cache, 0)
    def inner(a):
        adict = cache.copy()
        for key in range_cache[:a]:  # requires a to be an integer!
            adict[key] = 1
        return adict
    return inner

func1 = cached_version()  # initialize cache

def func2(a):
    keys = range(1, 51)
    adict = dict.fromkeys(keys[:a], 1)   # requires a to be an integer!
    for key in keys[a:]:
        adict[key] = 0
    return adict

def func3(a):
    adict = {}
    for key in range(1, 51):
        if key <= a:
            adict[key] = 1
        else:
            adict[key] = 0
    return adict

def func4(a):
    return {key: 1 if key <= a else 0 for key in range(1, 51)}

def func5(a):
    keys = range(1, 51) 
    adict = dict.fromkeys(keys[:a], 1)  # requires a to be an integer!
    adict.update(dict.fromkeys(keys[a:], 0))
    return adict

def func6(a):
    return dict(zip(range(1, 51), [1]*a + [0]*(49-a)))  # requires a to be an integer!

from itertools import chain

def func7(a):
    return dict(zip(range(1, 51), chain([1]*a, [0]*(49-a))))  # requires a to be an integer!

def func8(a):  # the one I originally mentioned
     adict = {key: int(key <= a) for key in range(1, 51)}
```

The timings were done on Python 3.5, Windows 10, there could be differences on other machines and other Python versions. Also note that the performance could be totally different if you had more keys instead of just `range(1, 51)`.

Comment: True, but this solution seems to be slower than either one of the functions I have, even without the `break`. You're right that the `break` statement could mess the results.

Comment: @PedroA okay, I did some timings and tried various combinations. I think I found a pretty fast one (although it's a closure with cache). :)

Comment: Nice, but I'm surprised `func3` is faster than `func4`, thought the comphrension would be faster?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I think the reason why comprehensions are typically faster is because they can avoid function lookups and calls like `.append` for `list`s or `.add` for `set`. But when assigning to keys for a dict that doesn't seem to be the case. It wasn't much slower though (I think only 5%)!

Comment: @MSeifert wow, that cache version seems to be really lightning fast. Any drawbacks / traps for using a closure with cache? And how would you pass `a` as an argument to `cached_version()`?

Comment: @PedroA It's a layer of indirection so it's harder to maintain in the long run (good documentation can help there). Also it increases the memory usage because the cached variables are kept in memory. If performance is an issue then it's worth trying such optimizations. However for every-day use I would prefer more readable solutions like the `{key: int(key <= a) for key in range(1, 51)}` comprehension. These are more readable and not too much slower.

Comment: @PedroA Do you mean `adict` with `a`?